# C++ maybe pointer type implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

### Motivation

This is intended to implement a C++ `maybe_ptr` type that can either hold a pointer to an underlying type `T` or a `nullptr`. The idea is to *guarantee*  at compile-time the absence of null pointer dereferencing errors in code that uses raw pointers.

Traditionally, these kinds of errors are prevented by the user having to guard pointer dereferencing by explicitly checking `nullptr`. For example:

```
void foo(int* n)
{
    if(n != nullptr)
    {
        bar(*n);
    }
}
```

The obvious danger is that the user forgets to check for `nullptr`, in which case it is undefined behavior that is not detected by the compiler and may not even be easily detected at run-time.

In contrast, `maybe_ptr` guarantees `nullptr` checking before the user is able to deference the raw pointer.

### Usage

Before getting to the implementation, let's see how `maybe_ptr` is used (leveraging C++11 lambdas):

```
void foo(const maybe_ptr<int>& ptr)
{
    bool ran = maybe_if(ptr, [](int* n)
    {
        bar(*n);  // never reached if n is null
    });
    // ran is true if ptr did not contain null (i.e. the lambda was run)
}
```

We can easily assign raw pointers to initialize `maybe_ptr`:

```
int n;
maybe_ptr<int> ptr = &n;
```

Note that `maybe_ptr` does not allow any direct access to the raw pointer once it is assigned:

```
maybe_ptr<std::string> ptr;
std::string* s = *ptr; // compiler error: no "*" operator defined
ptr->length(); // compiler error: no "->" operator defined
ptr->get(); // compiler error: "get" is inaccessible (private method)
```

The only way to access the pointer is through the `maybe_if` function, with a function pointer, lambda function, or functor. A couple overloaded `maybe_if` functions are provided for convenient, simultaneous access to multiple pointers within the same lambda function:

```
void foo(const maybe_ptr<int>& ptr1, const maybe_ptr<float>& ptr2)
{
    bool ran = maybe_if(ptr1, ptr2, [](int* n, float* x)
    {
        bar(*n, *x);  // never reached if n or x are null
    });
    // ran is true if ptr1 & ptr2 did not contain null
}
```

An additional function called `maybe_iff` is provided, if we want to just throw an exception on `nullptr`:

```
void foo(const maybe_ptr<int>& ptr)
{
    // throws exception if ptr contains null
    maybe_iff(ptr, [](int* n)
    {
        bar(*n); // never reached if n is null
    });
}
```

Finally, for additional safety, we also disable the copy constructor in `maybe_if` (similar to how `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied):

```
maybe_if<int> ptr1;
maybe_if<int> ptr2 = ptr1;  // compiler error: copy constructor is deleted
```

### Implementation

```
#pragma once

/// <summary>
/// Non-allocating "Maybe" type for raw pointers. The purpose of maybe_ptr 
/// is to prevent null pointer dereferencing by wrapping the raw pointer and forcing
/// all access to the raw pointer via a functor passed to maybe_if or maybe_iff
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// maybe_ptr does not own the underlying raw pointer (i.e. it does not manage its memory)
/// maybe_ptr cannot prevent dangling pointer errors, it only checks for nullptr
/// </remarks>
/// <typeparam name="T">the underlying type of the raw pointer</typeparam>
template <typename T>
class maybe_ptr {
public:

    /// <summary>
    /// Construct new maybe_ptr
    /// </summary>
    maybe_ptr() : _ptr(nullptr), _isNotNull(false) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Construct maybe_ptr from a raw pointer. maybe_ptr does not manage the
    /// memory of the pointer, it only restricts access to the pointer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">raw pointer to wrap with maybe_ptr</param>
    maybe_ptr(T* other)
    {
        set(other);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disable copy constructor to minimize risk dangling pointers
    /// </summary>
    maybe_ptr(const maybe_ptr&) = delete;

    /// <summary>
    /// Assignnment operator from raw pointer to this maybe_ptr. Previous raw pointer is overwitten.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">raw pointer to wrap with maybe_ptr</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    maybe_ptr<T>& operator=(T* other)
    {
        set(other);
        return *this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Bool operator to check if underlying raw pointer is not null
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>true if maybe_ptr is not null</returns>
    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        return _isNotNull;
    }

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Return raw pointer
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>underlying raw pointer</returns>
    T* get() const
    {
        return _ptr;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the underlying raw pointer and check if it is null
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ptr">raw pointer to wrap with this maybe_ptr</param>
    void set(T* ptr)
    {
        _ptr = ptr;
        _isNotNull = ptr != nullptr;
    }

    T* _ptr;
    bool _isNotNull;

    template<typename T, typename FunctorT> 
    friend bool maybe_if(const maybe_ptr<T>& ptr, typename FunctorT functor);

    template<typename T1, typename T2, typename FunctorT>
    friend bool maybe_if(const maybe_ptr<T1>& ptr1, const maybe_ptr<T2>& ptr2, typename FunctorT functor);

    template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename FunctorT>
    friend bool maybe_if(const maybe_ptr<T1>& ptr1, const maybe_ptr<T2>& ptr2, const maybe_ptr<T3>& ptr3, typename FunctorT functor);

    template<typename T, typename FunctorT>
    friend void maybe_iff(const T& ptr, typename FunctorT functor);

    template<typename T1, typename T2, typename FunctorT>
    friend void maybe_iff(const maybe_ptr<T1>& ptr1, const maybe_ptr<T2>& ptr2, typename FunctorT functor);

    template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename FunctorT>
    friend void maybe_iff(const maybe_ptr<T1>& ptr1, const maybe_ptr<T2>& ptr2, const maybe_ptr<T3>& ptr3, typename FunctorT functor);
};


/// <summary>
/// Run functor on ptr if ptr is not null, otherwise do nothing 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ptr">maybe_ptr to run functor on</param>
/// <param name="functor">function to if ptr is not null</param>
/// <returns>true if functor ran, false if it did not run</returns>
template<typename T, typename FunctorT>
bool maybe_if(const maybe_ptr<T>& ptr, typename FunctorT functor)
{
    if (ptr)
    {
        functor(ptr.get());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename FunctorT>
bool maybe_if(const maybe_ptr<T1>& ptr1, const maybe_ptr<T2>& ptr2, typename FunctorT functor)
{
    if (ptr1 && ptr2)
    {
        functor(ptr1.get(), ptr2.get());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename FunctorT>
bool maybe_if(const maybe_ptr<T1>& ptr1, const maybe_ptr<T2>& ptr2, const maybe_ptr<T3>& ptr3, typename FunctorT functor)
{
    if (ptr1 && ptr2 && ptr3)
    {
        functor(ptr1.get(), ptr2.get(), ptr3.get());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/// <summary>
/// Run functor on ptr if ptr is not null, otherwise throw exception
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ptr">maybe_ptr to run functor on</param>
/// <param name="functor">function to if ptr is not null</param>
/// <returns>true if functor ran, false if it did not run</returns>
template<typename T, typename FunctorT>
void maybe_iff(const T& ptr, typename FunctorT functor)
{
    THROW_ASSERT(ptr, "Unexpected null maybe_ptr")  // custom assert macro throws exception
    functor(ptr.get());
}

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename FunctorT>
void maybe_iff(const maybe_ptr<T1>& ptr1, const maybe_ptr<T2>& ptr2, typename FunctorT functor)
{
    THROW_ASSERT(ptr1 && ptr2, "Unexpected null maybe_ptr")
    functor(ptr1.get(), ptr2.get());
}

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename FunctorT>
void maybe_iff(const maybe_ptr<T1>& ptr1, const maybe_ptr<T2>& ptr2, const maybe_ptr<T3>& ptr3, typename FunctorT functor)
{
    THROW_ASSERT(ptr1 && ptr2 && ptr3, "Unexpected null maybe_ptr")
    functor(ptr1.get(), ptr2.get(), ptr3.get());
}
```

### Issues

1. The implementation has to explicitly define overloaded versions of `maybe_if` and `maybe_iff` for differing numbers of arguments. Currently only overloaded version for one, two or three `maybe_ptr` arguments are defined. It would be nice to replace this with C++11 variadic templates, but I ran into template argument deduction problems when I attempted to use variadic templates.
2. In a similar vein, it might be nice to eliminate the `FunctorT` template parameter in `maybe_if`, and explicitly define the `functor` argument type as `std::function<void(T*)>`, `std::function<void(T1*, T2*)>`, etc., however it appears that C++11 lambdas do not work in that case.
3. The `functor` seemingly has no way of returning any values. The `maybe_if` cannot return values from the `functor` argument (it is assumed to have void return type). The `functor` also cannot have any additional arguments through which values could be returned. However, this is not a huge deal because we can use lambda capture to assign values to variables in the enclosing scope.
4. The `maybe_if` usage is more verbose and syntactically awkward that traditional if-statement include guards. The becomes particularly acute when we have to do nested calls to maybe_if.
5. The functions `maybe_if` and `maybe_iff` and very similarly named, even though they have very different semantics. An alternative would be to rename `maybe_iff` to `maybe_if_assert` or `maybe_if_throw` but I decided not to do that in order to avoid making the API more verbose than it already is.
6. Use of `maybe_if` adds the overhead of a conditional branch in every call to `maybe_if`. The overhead can be amortized over multiple statements by including them within the same call to `maybe_if`, but the overhead still exists. However, I estimate that it is extremely minimal and worth the added safety.

**Note:** This idea was inspired by a different `Maybe` type implementation described [here](https://github.com/simonask/simonask.github.com/blob/master/maybe.markdown) ([full source](https://github.com/simonask/reflect/blob/master/base/maybe.hpp))

Comment: "The idea is to guarantee at compile-time the absence of null pointer dereferencing errors in code that uses raw pointers.". There is no `constexpr` in code, are you sure that the specification is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Variadic expansion

Until we get [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), we have to [use a workaround](http://articles.emptycrate.com/2016/05/14/folds_in_cpp11_ish.html) to check all the pointers

```
template<typename ... Args, typename Func>
bool maybe_if(const maybe_ptr<Args> &... args, Func function)
{
  bool result = true;
  (void)std::initializer_list<int>{ (result = result && args, 0)... };

    if (result)
    {
      function(args.get()...);
    }
    return result;
}
```

### Why return bool (or throw)?

The usefulness of an maybe type is more limited when you don't return a `maybe<result>`.

Instead of your

```
bool ran = maybe_if(ptr, bar);
if (ran) 
{ 
    bar happened, do other stuff
    /* why didn't we just if (ptr) { bar(*ptr) } here? */ 
}
```

Instead it is

```
auto bar_res = maybe_if(ptr, bar);
auto baz_res = maybe_if(bar_res, baz);
// etc...
bool last_res = maybe_if(baz_res, last);
return last_res;
```

Doing that would resolve points 3-5, however you are explicitly non-owning

### Don't use std::function

Your worry that extra overhead will occur from ifs is misplaced, you should be much more worried about hiding functions in `std::function<>`, which is a very heavyweight construction, which is much more suitable for storing [Callables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable)

Comment: why is `std::function<>` heavyweight? Are you talking about generally or in this particular context?

Comment: in comparison to a template parameter, which can easily be inlined, `std::function<>` hides the implementation.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal, I believe that main reason is that it uses type erasure, which potentially prevents optimizations done by compiler. Current std::function copies arguments, and (if it exceeds small object optimization's size) will make heap allocation. Then function gets out of scope, it will be freed. The free might not be immediate system call, but allocation probably will, which is expensive in performance sensitive code. Also, cache coherence comes into play, but it is more low level issue.

Comment: Thanks. The tip on variadic templates and std::function is good to know.

Comment: Regarding "Why return bool?", as you noted, this is problematic if the `Maybe` type does not own the underlying pointer. One of the design objectives of my`maybe_ptr` implementation was to safely handle raw pointers returned by third-party library. The libraries in question retain ownership of the pointers, so it is not possible for `maybe_ptr` to own them. The only usefulness of this `maybe_ptr` is that it allows the type system to enforce pointer `nullptr` checking before pointer access, whereas if we just use `if (ptr) { bar(*ptr) }` then the `nullptr` checking is not enforced.

Comment: `template<typename ... Args, typename Func>
bool maybe_if(const maybe_ptr<Args> &... args, Func function)` is this valid? Variadic parameters are only allowed at the end of the parameter list AFAIK.